# Different SQL query efficiency

Tags: mysql, sql-optimization

There are business requirements in the project that relate to a few tables. The following two query options are beneficial for performance optimization in those cases. How should I choose?
   First:Filter the Cartesian product:

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 ，table2 where table1.id=table2.id
```

Second:Left outer connection mode or right outer connection mode

```
 select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Please tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The two are not equivalent. `LEFT JOIN` will return `table1` rows that don't have a matching `table2` row, Cartesian product will not return these rows.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE Use the above two ways to query out the same data, but I would like to know in which case the use of that way the performance will be better

Comment: These two queries select different data (have different outcomes). They are not comparable in that way.

Comment: if you want the exact same queries you should make an INNER join and not a LEFT JOIN. Then the performance will be excatly the same. At the moment you compare 2 queries that are  not necessarily retrieving the same data so it is irrelevant.

Comment: and the answer is: use the EXPLICIT JOIN syntax.

Comment: @Thomas G Does he have some truth? Naresh Shahi

Comment: thr truth is that your answer is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write them in a form where they give the same results, expect the query analyser to give you identical* query plans. That said **Use JOIN not `,`**, because `,` is much less clear, and has been deprecated for decades

If you want to compare the performance of two different queries, the easiest method is to run both and compare how long they took, although checking that they are doing different things by comparing the query plans (`EXPLAIN query text here` in mysql will give you the plan for a query)

Note that saying "I know they give different results, but I want the faster one" is never a sensible thing to say in programming. You should always know exactly what results you want.

I.e.

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 ，table2 where table1.id=table2.id
```

has the same meaning as

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

and

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

has the same meaning as

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 ，table2 where table1.id=table2.id 
union 
select table1.a , null from table1 where table1.id not in (select table2.id from table2)
```

And the join forms that you didn't use:

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 right join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

has the same meaning as

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 ，table2 where table1.id=table2.id 
union 
select null, table2.b from table2 where table2.id not in (select table1.id from table1)
```

And

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 full join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

has the same meaning as

```
select table1.a ,table2.b from table1 ，table2 where table1.id=table2.id 
union 
select table1.a , null from table1 where table1.id not in (select table2.id from table2)
union 
select null, table2.b from table2 where table2.id not in (select table1.id from table1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Second query is faster. it doesn't have nested condition. SQL engine treat join as a single table or a view.

In my openion first query works as a "For loop" so run time complexity is O(n), and seconf query works as Switch Case in worsecase runtime complexity is O(log n).

Comment: In any case the second is better than the first one?

Comment: SQL goes through a query plan step. OP's two queries will have similar plans (identical if he changes to `join` from `left join`)